# How to get MakeIndex working in WinEdt

Tags: winedt, makeindex

I hope this is a simple question with a simple answer. I am using WinEdt and there is a TeX menu with "Make Index" as an option.

I have gone into Execution Modes and found the "MakeIndex" entry, added the executable in MikTeX and (based on the note [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing#MakeIndex_settings_in_WinEdt) tried to add the "-s [name].ist" to the command line.

Here is an image of what my execution mode screen looks like:
[image]

But the "Make Index" command under the TeX menu item is ghosted, so I cannot run it.

There is also supposed to be a command line option in an Accessories|Run... command, but I don't have a Run command under the Accessories menu item.

Edit: I do have \makeindex in the source and .idx files are generated. I just don't have access to the MakeIndex tool within WinEdt---it is grayed out and the keyboard shortcut does not work.

[image]

Edit: I have been able to successfully use the commandline version by clicking Accessories|CommandLine. This ran without any errors.

Comment: Delete the contents of `Executable` field in `Command Line` and press OK. WinEdt will find `makeindex` on its own.

Comment: What do you mean with "ghosted"? Perhaps "grayed out", unavailable? If so, this means that you haven't generated a `.idx` needed to run makeindex.

Comment: What you call the  `Run` command in the Accessories menu is probably `Command Prompt`. As to `Make Index` being greyed, it certainly means you have no `.idx` file.

Comment: Do you have a `\makeindex` command in your `.tex` file that generates the `.idx` one?

Comment: @Arzigoglu, I do have a \makeindex command, and I also have .idx files in my directory. I removed the contents of "Executable" and WinEdt recreated them, but now there is a "(!)" next to the entry in the Execution Mode screen. "MakeIndex" is still grayed out. I'm attaching a screenshot showing the idx files.

Comment: @Bernard, I do have .idx files in the directory. See screenshot.

Comment: @Arzigoglu, thanks for the note on the Command Prompt. I was able to use that to make the indexes.

Comment: What package are you using to generate indexes? `imakeidx` perhaps? In this case there is no need to run makeindex (pdflatex does all the job), but you should put makeindex options in the `\makeindex` command directly, e.g. `\makeindex[name=people,...,options=-s people.ist]`

Comment: @Arzigoglu I'm using memoir, which emulates makeidx

Comment: I tried using \makeindex[name=people,options=-s people.ist] and I got a "missing \begin{document}" error. I tried putting it later in the document, and I got an error saying it was only allowed in preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an editor that is able to run makeindex when there is not an `.idx` file with the same name of the `.tex` file.

To overcome this, try this. Just after

```
\documentclass{memoir}
```

add

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex people}
```

or

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex -s people.ist people}
```

if you have a `people.ist` style file and recompile the file.

Comment: Nice! This worked great!

Answer (score 0):

It [appears](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/WinEdt/conversations/messages/12242) that WinEdt simply does not have the capability to register any .idx files other than a generic one whose name is the same as the file being compiled.